# Workaround for lack of init-file on AWS RDS MYSQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to replicate my existing hosting configuration on AWS.  My problem is that in the current MARIADB configuration, I have an init file that loads several memory tables.  And apparently AWS RDS precludes the use of init scripts.

My work around is below... It involves scheduling a recurrent event that checks how long the server has been up and runs the init code if it goes below 300 secs (indicating a reboot).  This seems to work but feels a little kludgy.

Any better approaches? Any downsides to the kludge?

```
BEGIN
SET @uptime := (SELECT variable_value
    FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS
    WHERE VARIABLE_NAME LIKE  'uptime');
IF @uptime <300 then 
     Put init code here....
END IF;
END
```

You will need to give yourself privilege to set up event Link

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/

Comment: maybe the application code that uses these tables catches the 'not exists' exception and loads/creates them.